# d3: How to use brush and zoom together

Tags: d3.js

I'd like to combine brushing and zooming on the same chart. So far I can brush, and I can zoom. What I can't do is brush then zoom, or zoom then brush. Once I do either of these combined actions, any brushed area becomes mis-matched with the actual bars that are "selected".

For the visualization I'm creating, all bars are selected by default (selected bars are blue). These are the use cases I'd like to support:

1. Zoom into an area on the chart and brush to select some bars
2. Brush to select some bars, then zoom into that area and refine the selection so that it's right up against the bars I'm interested in.
3. Bonus interaction would be if the brush extents snap to the beginning and end of the closest bars.

Here's what I've got so far: https://codesandbox.io/s/zoom-and-brush-hs9lwp

TIA

Comment: Nearly every example I've seen that combine brushing and zooming online use the brush to zoom to that selection, or brushing on one chart zooms another chart. That's not what I'm going for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

In the zoom handler, I needed to update the brush if it's drawn. I did this by getting the existing selection extent, then rescaling those points, then move the brush to the new coordinates.

In the brush handler, I just needed to use a copy of the original scale that has been updated for any zooming performed.

There's probably a better way, especially the zoom handler part, but this works for now. If anyone has a better/cleaner way of doing this, please let me know.

Updated example at: https://codesandbox.io/s/zoom-and-brush-forked-pr1g3c